# Setup keystore and truststore in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, keystore, trust-relationship

Im new to AWS, mutual authentication. However I have not setup elastic bean stalk. I am working with a payment API. The organization that has setup the API requires a keystore and trust store to be setup

I have signed up my for AWS and simply setup an nginx server on redhat linux and put up my php web application. I have read alot of blogs and articles and most of them suggest the use of an application platform like Weblogic, WebSphere and so. My questions are

1) Because I havent set up elastic beanstalk...Should I set it up so that I can setup locations of a keystore and trust store?

2)If I do setup elastic bean stalk and its cli, does the cli allow me to select a web service/application on mythat will be referring to keystore and trust store?

Or am I simply setting a location of the keystore and trust store so that I can have a handshake with the payment API and from henceforth, I can use the payment API resources?